# Indexing data in elasticsearch from postgres using express(sequelize)/Logstash

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch, logstash, sequelize.js

I have no prior experience to any full text search client like `Solr`. I am using `Sequelize` as nodejs ORM for postgres with Express. 
So my question is how should i approach the problem of Storing data to elasticsearch from postgres in above given setup.

I tried using `logstash-jdbc-input-plugin` as described in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) but i am having problem in indexing related data like(one to many). For example Author have many Books then json would look like

```
{
  "authorname" : [
    {
      "name" : "book1",
      "description" : "book2"
    },
    {
      "name" : "book2",
      "description" : "book2"
    }
  ]
}
```

So Query like this is Fine with `Sequelize` because database will return 2 rows and ORM(Sequelize) have its own way to make it a single json object with array of books object. But how to do this type of thing with `logstash-jdbc-input-plugin` ?

So now i am thinking about Querying postgres using sequelize on regular interval then somehow storing the data to elastic search node. If this approach is right then Can anyone point me in the right direction that how to do it? Some links will be very help full.

And am I on the right track to solving this problem. Any suggestions, guideline or sample code will be very help full for me. 
Thanks

Comment: how frequently your data changes in postgress(update/deletes to primary data)?

Comment: @user3775217 It dose not changes much frequently. It Mostly the one time Creation  of all related Data.

Comment: Now i am trying [elasticsearch-jdbc](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc)... will post the detail Soon.